# Can TiledMaps be changed on slick2d?

Tags: java, slick2d

I'm trying to make quite simple game, you're just wandering in rooms, when you use the door you get to other room.
Here's how it looks [image: screen]

i use this simple if to change

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
      sprite = up;
      if(!isBlocked(x,y - delta * 0.1f) && y > 0) {
         sprite.update(delta);                // lower delta = lower speed animation
          y -= delta * 0.1f;
      }
      if(isDoor(x,y - delta * 0.1f)) {
          currentMap = currentRoom.getNorth().getMap();
          currentRoom = currentRoom.getNorth();
      }
}
```

"currentMap" is TiledMap which currently is being rendered. "currentRoom" is current Room who has TiledMap inside it, because i need some more stuff to store about room. And the problem is that when i go to door, game immediately shuts down with null pointer, however before crashing i can see a glimpse that map is changed.

Full error report:

```
ERROR:null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at not.zuul.world.GameMain.update(GameMain.java:143)
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:663)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
at not.zuul.world.GameMain.main(GameMain.java:40)
Sat Oct 25 21:18:51 CEST 2014 ERROR:Game.update() failure - check the game code.
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Game.update() failure - check the game code.
at org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer.updateAndRender(GameContainer.java:669)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.gameLoop(AppGameContainer.java:411)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:321)
at not.zuul.world.GameMain.main(GameMain.java:40)
```

Some additional code, these are called on init. Rooms - hashmap of strings containing letter for what direction doors it has (key) , and tiledmap for value ( there 15 diferrent rooms because of diferrent door combinations.

And game_map is again hashmap with String (name) for key and class Room for value. and i use "setRooms" to set "neighbour" for that room, or in other where those doors leads, order is (north, south, east, west)

```
public void initAllRooms() throws SlickException {
    rooms = new HashMap<String, TiledMap>();
    rooms.put("N", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north.tmx"));
    rooms.put("S", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_south.tmx"));
    rooms.put("E", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_east.tmx"));
    rooms.put("W", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NE", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_east.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NS", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_south.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("SE", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_south_east.tmx"));
    rooms.put("SW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_south_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("EW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_east_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NSE", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_south_east.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NSW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_south_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NEW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_east_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("SEW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_south_east_west.tmx"));
    rooms.put("NSEW", new TiledMap("resources/map/Rooms/room_north_south_east_west.tmx"));
}

public void initMap() throws SlickException {
    game_map = new HashMap<String, Room>();
    game_map.put("outside", new Room(rooms.get("N"), "You're outside."));
    game_map.put("mainHall", new Room(rooms.get("NSEW"), "You're in main hall."));
    game_map.put("emptyRoom", new Room(rooms.get("NE"), "You're in empty room."));
    game_map.put("bathRoom", new Room(rooms.get("S"), "You're in bathroom"));
    game_map.put("kitchen", new Room(rooms.get("NW"), "You're in kitchen"));
    game_map.put("diningRoom", new Room(rooms.get("NS"), "You;re in dining room"));
    game_map.put("backYard", new Room(rooms.get("SE"), "You're in back yard"));
    game_map.put("storageRoom", new Room(rooms.get("W"), "You're in storage room"));

    game_map.get("outside").setRooms(game_map.get("mainHall"), null, null, null);
    game_map.get("mainHall").setRooms(game_map.get("diningRoom"), game_map.get("outside"),
            game_map.get("emptyRoom"), game_map.get("kitchen"));
    game_map.get("emptyRoom").setRooms(game_map.get("bathRoom"), null, game_map.get("mainHall"), null );
    game_map.get("bathRoom").setRooms(null, game_map.get("emptyRoom"), null, null);
    game_map.get("kitchen").setRooms(null, null, null, game_map.get("mainHall"));
    game_map.get("diningRoom").setRooms(game_map.get("backYard"), game_map.get("mainHall)"), null, null);
    game_map.get("backYard").setRooms(null, game_map.get("diningRoom"), game_map.get("storageRoom"), null);
    game_map.get("storageRoom").setRooms(null, null, null, game_map.get("backYard"));

}
```

Comment: I think i figured it out, when player goes to other room, i dont change his coordinates and he goes out of bounds of room

Comment: Yup that was the problem, sorry for bothering you guys :)

Answer (score -1):

Can't really help unless you provide the stacktrace and the line(s) the stacktrace is coming from.

EDIT: Still need to see what line the crash is occurring on.

Comment: Please post comments as comments, not as answers. Use the "add a comment" link below the original question.

Comment: I don't have 50 reputation, so I can't

Comment: Then get some more rep like the rest of us did. The more you prioritize your desires over the standards set by the community, the lower your rep will go and you'll never get to 50.